# SQLite use Order By, but have another delimiter put things at bottom of list

Tags: sqlite, sql-order-by

Is there a way to use a SQLite query to get a list of things ordered by 1 delimiter, but have another delimiter grab from the results and put those results at the bottom of the list?

For example, if i have my testTable that looks something like this:

```
id price date
1 2.00 12/10/2011
2 1.00 09/10/2011
3 3.00 01/01/2012
4 2.00 02/04/2012
```

If i wanted to sort it by date, i would use:

```
SELECT * FROM testTable ORDER BY DATE ASC
```

this would give me:

```
id price date
2 1.00 09/10/2011
1 2.00 12/10/2011
3 3.00 01/01/2012
4 2.00 02/04/2012
```

But, what if I want the list sorted by dates, but I want the items that cost 2.00 to be at the bottom?  I would want the result to look like:

```
id price date
2 1.00 09/10/2011
3 3.00 01/01/2012
1 2.00 12/10/2011
4 2.00 02/04/2012
```

Is there a specific query I can use to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: A special sort order where items with a specific numeric value in one column come bottom? That sounds like the sort of thing I'd do with multiple queries and reassembly in the caller…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
    FROM testTable 
    ORDER BY CASE WHEN price = 2.00 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
             DATE
```